# boundeness solutions system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the ode's

> $$u''+a(x)u=0\quad\quad(1)$$

with $a \in \mathcal{C}^1([0,+\infty[)$, and

> $$u'' + (a(x) + b(x))u = 0\quad\quad(2).$$

We assume that all solutions of $(1)$ are bounded, and  we suppose that $b(x)\to0$ when $x \to 0$ or $\int_0^{\infty} |b(s)|ds < \infty$,

> The question is: how we can prove that the solutions of $(2)$ are bounded on $[0,+\infty[$?

Comment: Why your equations numbering is inconsistent? By the way, your question is not clear.

Comment: i edit my post. the question is: if all solutions of (1) are bounded on $[0,+\infty[$, and if $b(x)-->0$ when $x-->0$ (or $\int |b(s)|ds < +\infty$, how to prouve that all solutions of (2) are bounded on $[0,+\infty[$

Answer (score 0):

Let $u_1$ and $u_2$ be solutions of (1) (which are bounded by assumption). Then let us find the solution of (2), $u''+a(x)u= f(s)$, where $f(s)=-b(s)u$, by variation of parameters: $u_p= v_1u_1+v_2u_2$ where

$v_1=-\int_0^x\frac{u_2(s)f(s)}{W(u_1, u_2)}ds$ and $v_2=\int_0^x\frac{u_1(s)f(s)}{W(u_1, u_2)}ds$. Here u is the solution of (1) which is also bounded by assumption. It follows from (1) that the Wronskian $W=c=constant\neq0$. Thus being the solution of (2),

$u_p(x)=-u_1(x)\int_0^x\frac{u_2(s)f(s)}{c}ds+u_2(x)(x)\int_0^x\frac{u_1(s)f(s)}{c}ds$

or

$u_p(x)=u_1(x)\int_0^x\frac{u_2(s)b(s)u(s)}{c}ds-u_2(x)\int_0^x\frac{u_1(s)b(s)u(s)}{c}ds$.

Therefore, using the boundedness of $u$, $u_1$ and $u_2$ and the fact that $\int_0^\infty  b(s)ds<\infty$, we see that $u_p$ is bounded on $[0, \infty)$.